# Como mudar a forma de exibição de erros do php?

Tags: php

Desde que formatei o servidor não consigo mais mudar a forma em que os erros eram exibidos. Hoje os erros são apresentados da seguinte forma
[image: Exibição de erro atual]

e eu gostaria que fosse exibido como no WAMP

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu arquivo php.ini está configurado da seguinte forma:

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE
html_errors = On
```

Versão do php

```
PHP Version 5.5.13-1~dotdeb.1
```

Servidor

```
Debian 7 "Wheezy"
```

Comment: Veja se o [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/screens.php) está instalado

Comment: @perdeu não instalei ainda, vou testar com ele se mudar alguma coisa

Comment: Testei no windows, removi apenas o comentário da linha `[XDebug]
zend_extension = caminho` do php.ini e a mensagem de erro veio com aquele laranjado.

Comment: Estou instalando xDebug aqui, é cheio das dependências, que possuem suas dependências, e o debian não facilita a vida em nada kkkkk

Comment: @perdeu era o xDebug mesmo :D coloca como resposta pra eu poder marcar como correta

Comment: Acho melhor vc escrever a resposta e colocar quais os passos/comandos executou no linux e também se foi preciso alterar o php.ini ou a pasta ext  para instalar o xdebug.

Comment: ok, vou fazer isso entao

Comment: Caso o que você queira apenas uma forma mais bonita e organizada de vizualizar erros, vale a pena dar uma olhada neste projeto: https://github.com/JosephLenton/PHP-Error

Comment: uma coisa boa da resposta / opção  usando set_error_handler é que ela te libera da necessidade de configurar xdebug (opção esta que pode nem estar disponível em host compartilhado) ao mesmo tempo em que te dá total liberdade para trabalhar o layout da tela de errro ;-)

Comment: Realmente em servidores compartilhados não tenho essa possibilidade, mas nesses servidores eu não vou exibir erros, tenho que exibi-los para produção e depois ocultar qualquer erro que possa ocorrer por questões estéticas para o cliente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer isso deve-se instalar o xDebug.
Como ele é cheio de dependencias temos que instalar algumas coisas primeiro

Passo 1: Instalar o PEAR

> apt-get install php-pear

Passo 2: Instalar PHP5-DEV

> apt-get install  php5-dev

Passo 3: Instalar o Libcurl3

> apt-get install libcurl3-openssl-dev

Passo 4: Instalar o PECL-HTTP(opcional)

> pecl install pecl_http

Passo 5: Instalar o xDebug :D

> pecl install xdebug

Passo 6: Adicionar a seguinte linha no seu php.ini

> zend_extension=xdebug.so

E é isso, agora seu php vai exibir os erros com a caixa laranja, os arrays em cascata, vai ser capaz de debugar o código entre outras coisas...

Fontes:
[Chirale](http://chirale.wordpress.com/2008/11/23/pear-install-quick-howto-on-debian-lenny-imagegraph/)
[MKFOSTER](http://www.mkfoster.com/2009/01/04/how-to-install-a-php-pecl-extensionmodule-on-ubuntu/)
[xDebug - Site oficial](http://xdebug.org/docs/install)

Answer (score 2):

Você deve usar set_error_handler e setar uma função sua para tratar e exibir os erros como você desejar

Fonte: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

```
<?php
// error handler function
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }

    //CUSTOMIZAR SUAS TELAS DE ERRO AQUI

    switch ($errno) {
    case E_USER_ERROR:
        echo "<b>My ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        echo "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile";
        echo ", PHP " . PHP_VERSION . " (" . PHP_OS . ")<br />\n";
        echo "Aborting...<br />\n";
        exit(1);
        break;

    case E_USER_WARNING:
        echo "<b>My WARNING</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    case E_USER_NOTICE:
        echo "<b>My NOTICE</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    default:
        echo "Unknown error type: [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;
    }

    /* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
    return true;
}

// function to test the error handling
function scale_by_log($vect, $scale)
{
    if (!is_numeric($scale) || $scale <= 0) {
        trigger_error("log(x) for x <= 0 is undefined, you used: scale = $scale", E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    if (!is_array($vect)) {
        trigger_error("Incorrect input vector, array of values expected", E_USER_WARNING);
        return null;
    }

    $temp = array();
    foreach($vect as $pos => $value) {
        if (!is_numeric($value)) {
            trigger_error("Value at position $pos is not a number, using 0 (zero)", E_USER_NOTICE);
            $value = 0;
        }
        $temp[$pos] = log($scale) * $value;
    }

    return $temp;
}

// set to the user defined error handler
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");

// trigger some errors, first define a mixed array with a non-numeric item
echo "vector a\n";
$a = array(2, 3, "foo", 5.5, 43.3, 21.11);
print_r($a);

// now generate second array
echo "----\nvector b - a notice (b = log(PI) * a)\n";
/* Value at position $pos is not a number, using 0 (zero) */
$b = scale_by_log($a, M_PI);
print_r($b);

// this is trouble, we pass a string instead of an array
echo "----\nvector c - a warning\n";
/* Incorrect input vector, array of values expected */
$c = scale_by_log("not array", 2.3);
var_dump($c); // NULL

// this is a critical error, log of zero or negative number is undefined
echo "----\nvector d - fatal error\n";
/* log(x) for x <= 0 is undefined, you used: scale = $scale" */
$d = scale_by_log($a, -2.5);
var_dump($d); // Never reached
?>
```